# Automatically detect pdf documents that needs OCR recognition in node

Tags: node.js, pdf, tesseract

I have been using node pdfutils package to extract text from some pdf documents to a text file. Sometimes the output is a blank text file because the pdf document is scanned as a non editable one and in that case, I use node-tesseract to extract text. I'm switching manually between both strategies as needed.
Does anyone know how to detect the automatically the difference?

Comment: Always try to extract text first, and if the output file is blank, use OCR. Seems to me you already have all the pieces of the puzzle.

Comment: You're right but, I don't know how to test if the output file is blank! (Perhaps my question wasn't adequately formulated).

Comment: @franaf: Exactly your question has to have more details about the code & logic, so that we can understand what exactly you are doing and try to help you out. Thank you. Hope you will update with some more details..

Comment: these are might useful : https://github.com/zetahernandez/pdf-to-text and https://github.com/nisaacson/pdf-extract